# When redirecting from index.html , the redirection should be to another HTML or to a JSP page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications

I have a basic index.html page :

[image]

Instead of that , I want to put a simple `Login` , where the user enter the `username` and `password` , and only then redirect the user to a page with multiple options .

When I'm redirecting the user from `index.html` , should I redirect to another HTML page , or to a JSP page ? is there any difference ?

Regards

Comment: It will depend on the web page file extension, if you have a jsp page to handle this data, then you will redirect to index.jsp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either redirect to an HTML page or a JSP one.
But I noticed that you are willing to have a Login page. It is better to use something like `j_security_check` or `Spring Security`. you can see some tutorials [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials). It gives you comfort achieving your goal.

Comment: I'm working with tomcat7 , he works with `6` , do you have an example for tomcat7 maybe ? thanks . +1 for the great answer !

Comment: There are not much differences @Jackcole. I'm using tomcat7 and there is no problem. What are you exactly looking for?

Comment: Note that Mykong is using a `pom` file and `web.xml` file , and in my project I have none of the above.

Comment: If you are developing a web application, you have to have web.xml. I suggest you to use spring security to secure your webpages. For that, you have to learn about spring security first. But I assure you that, it's an easy task.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on you page requirements and content, if you have any content that you need to render from the server end, then you will have to use .JSP extension. If there is all but static content on you page and simple form submission then using a simple html page will be a good practice, as it will save you a page render on the server end...

Comment: What I exactly want is : user enters `username+passowrd` --> moving to another page where he/she can choose between options that would require to use MYSQL server. JSP then  ?

Comment: Yes, It is a good practice to render the webpage at your server end, as it gives you more control over the page. It helps in maintaining sessions of both anonymous and known users on your web application..

Answer (score 1):

> When I'm redirecting the user from index.html , should I redirect to another HTML page , or to a JSP page ? is there any difference ?

Redirecting simply sends a header to client saying that make a new GET to the URL specified, So now you can see if you redirect it to jsp page it will send the response header to client with that URL specified